# Why isn't my model moving with my rig?

Tags: rigging

I'm very new to Blender and I have a rigging question. I imported my model from Zbrush, and built a rig for the character. I select the rig, then the model, and pair them. Now when I move my rig, the model doesn't move. Am I missing a step, or could there be something wrong with my rig? Any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parent the mesh to the rig, so you've selected them in the incorrect order. Once you do that you should get a list of armature deform options in the parenting menu when you apply the parenting.